# Втиснуть WHERE в двойной MySQL запрос

Tags: mysql

Приветствую всех вошедших

Есть сложный запрос, не понимаю как вставить туда WHERE newfield=5

```
select    b1.amount - b2.amount as amount1
from      table1 b1
join      table2 b2 on b1.id = b2.id + 1
having    amount1 < 0
```

Пробовал уже по разному, вообще никак. Единственное что сработало

```
select    b1.amount - b2.amount as amount1
from      table1 b1
join      table2 b2 on b1.id = b2.id + 1
having    amount1 < 0 and id>0
```

но, если переписать поле id на любое другое - не работает. Подскажите, как переписать запрос?

Comment: Почему бы не так?

    select    b1.amount - b2.amount as amount1
    from      table1 b1
    join      table2 b2 on b1.id = b2.id + 1
    where     b1.amount1 < 0 and b1.id>0

Comment: Оно самое! Только вот есть нюанс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуйте.

```
select    b1.amount - b2.amount as amount1
from      table1 b1, table2 b2
where     
  (b1.id = (b2.id + 1)) and 
  ((b1.amount-b2.amount) < 0) and 
  (b1.newfieldd=5);
```

p.s. совершенно не понимаю чем это отличается от join но у меня так всегда работало))